# I have a Runtime Warning when I use __name__ variable in my script

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu-12.04

I tried to use `___name__` at the beginning of my python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# Comments...
# blabla
#

__name__="cigarline_by_pos.py"
__synopsis__ = "cigarline_by_pos.py | INPUT_BAM_FILE  --output OUTPUT_FILE [--output OUTPUT_FILE_R2 --readsplit]"
__example__ = "cigarline_by_pos.py hg18.bam  --output hg18_read1.csv --output  hg18_read2.csv --readsplit"
__date__ = "05/2013"
__authors__ = "Frederic Escudie & Antoine Leleu"
__keywords__ = "SAM Alignment"
__description__ = "Sum by position the status of reads. This provides for example the number of reads that have a mismatch at first base."

__version__ = '2.3.1'


import argparse,re,sys

the rest of the code...
```

but then Python prints a warning:

```
cigarline_by_pos.py:29: RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'cigarline_by_pos' not found while handling absolute import
  import argparse,re,sys
```

and I have no idea of what it could come from.

I just know that if I remove the line with `___name__` my script works, but I want this variable.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not set `__name__` in your script; Python already sets it and relies on the value for other purposes such as importing. The `__name__` value of a python script or module can be changed but you need to know what you are doing and understand Python's internals before you should attempt to do so.

**Don't set double underscore variables *in general* even.** They are reserved for Python use only; only set them when they are documented as settable, such as `__all__` in a module.

See the [Python data model documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) for an overview of what double-underscore names (dunder names) are currently in use.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer ! i didn't know about this, now i'm less stupid ;)

Comment: Not a problem, you are doing fine. :-)

Comment: i just noticed that if i move all the lines with the underscore variables below the import line, it works. i just don't know exactly why it works with that.

Comment: @antoine4790: because `__name__` has special meaning in Python, and it is used to determine relative imports. By moving the line below the `import` you moved it into a position where the `import` statement sees the correct value for `__name__`.